# openshift: `<class:Model>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observing (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openshift

I have Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.0.2 and an OpenShift free account.

Everything was okay until I tried to configure email settings [like so](http://www.arubystory.com/2013/12/tutorial-todo-rails-openshift.html):

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://todo-yourdomainhere.rhcloud.com' } 
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://todo-yourdomainhere.rhcloud.com' 
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: 'smtp.gmail.com', port: 587, user_name: 'your_username@gmail.com', password: 'your_password', authentication: 'plain', enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

Then I had this error:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources
```

I tried this:

```
bundle install —path vendor/cache
```

And this:

```
gem install rake && bundle install
```

(answers from here [Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801899/bundlergemnotfound-could-not-find-rake-10-3-2-in-any-of-the-sources))

After that when I push I get this error:

```
16:16icdortonway git push openshift openshift:master
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:13:in `<class:Model>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observing (NameError)
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:6:in `<module:OpenShift>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.31.11/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/frontend_proxy.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.31.11/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
remote:     from /usr/bin/gear:21:in `<main>'
To ssh://...@dortonway-dortonway.rhcloud.com/~/git/dortonway.git/
 ! [remote rejected] openshift -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://...@dortonway-dortonway.rhcloud.com/~/git/dortonway.git/'
16:16icdortonway
```

If I try to restart the server from an OpenShift panel, I get so:

```
    Enabling server ...

/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:13:in `<class:Model>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observing (NameError)
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:6:in `<module:OpenShift>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.31.11/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/frontend_proxy.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.31.11/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/ruby/sdk.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
Enabling server ...

/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:13:in `<class:Model>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observing (NameError)
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:6:in `<module:OpenShift>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common/models/model.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-common-1.28.4/lib/openshift-origin-common.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.31.11/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/frontend_proxy.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.31.11/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/ruby/sdk.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
Failed to execute: 'control enable-server' for /var/lib/openshift/.../haproxy
Failed to execute: 'control enable-server' for /var/lib/openshift/.../haproxy
```

I tried to comment email settings but it doesn't change anything.

So I can't push or restart the server from the OpenShift panel.

Can anybody say how to fix it?
Thanks!