# Rake Aborted Error - Can't install bundler - When install GitLab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install gitLab server in my Virtual Machines, When I Execute the command: `sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws`, I got this:

> Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
>       Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources

And my gem source is:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/git/gitlab# gem sources -l
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://ruby.taobao.org/
https://rubygems.org/
```

When I  run `gem install rake-10.3.2`, I got this:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake-10.3.2' (>= 0) in any repository

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801899/bundlergemnotfound-could-not-find-rake-10-3-2-in-any-of-the-sources)

Comment: it shows  "Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing rake with this command

```
gem install rake -v 10.3.2
```

Comment: It can install rake-10.3.2,But sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws still can't works!

Comment: could you post your Gemfile? Maybe rake is specified in either development, test, mysql or aws section? Also could you try 'sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment'

Comment: After two days of efforts，I finally solve this problem , It does have a relationship with Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Delete your `Gemfile.lock`

and run the command:

```
 bundle install
```

Comment: It does't works! And I got this message:
    
    Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze 
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* source: rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/
* rails (~> 4.1.0)
..........