# Bundler::GemNotFound when deploying to Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift, gem-bundler

I just published my rails app to Openshift and I got the error message:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

The log file says:

> Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

I do not know how to debug this issue. This has happened to about 3 apps I have deployed in the last couple of hours.

Hers is a link to the full ruby log file:

https://gist.github.com/kinsomicrote/e3715be509a7375758ef

Comment: `Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`  - you have not installed the gems your application depends on.

Comment: In case you think that you *have* installed rake, have a look at this question - it's a different version of the rake gem but might be the same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801899/bundlergemnotfound-could-not-find-rake-10-3-2-in-any-of-the-sources

Comment: What version of Ruby & Rails does your application use?  And what version did you choose on OpenShift when creating your application?  It might help if you post your Gemfile & Gemfile.lock also.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have problems with gems and passanger.

Did you run `bundle install` on the host? (if you have Gemfile)

If you already do, try to install puma or thin, and start webserver running `bundle exec puma -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -d`

to check if it working. Passanger sometimes is hard to setup.

Comment: The issue seems to be with Passanger. Is there a recommended way to install puma or thin to work with openshift?

Comment: I have installed puma but the default server is still passanger. I used this code `rhc env set OPENSHIFT_RUBY_SERVER=puma -a YOUR_APP_NAME` to set puma as default server but it is still passanger.

Comment: I have been able to set puma as default server. I am getting 503 service time-out
Here is the link to the ruby log: https://gist.github.com/kinsomicrote/21bd02aaf63a8308a4e5
Thanks.