# Errors while setting up rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, activesupport

After re-installing ruby and doing countless `bundle install`'s I keep on getting this error when I try to run debug, please help:

```
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- js_regex
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/elena/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/client_side_validations-9942c8cc822d/lib/client_side_validations/core_ext/regexp.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/elena/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/client_side_validations-9942c8cc822d/lib/client_side_validations/core_ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/elena/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/client_side_validations-9942c8cc822d/lib/client_side_validations/active_model.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/elena/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/client_side_validations-9942c8cc822d/lib/client_side_validations.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/home/elena/Dev/tibdit-application/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:43:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:43:in `block in exec_app_rails'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `exec_app_rails'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/elena/Dev/tibdit-application/bin/rails:16:in `load'
/home/elena/Dev/tibdit-application/bin/rails:16:in `<top (required)>'
```

My gem file:

```
ruby '2.2.1'
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'node', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.1'
gem 'opengraph_parser'
gem 'blockchain'
gem 'block_io'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'geoip'
gem 'metainspector', '~> 4.7.2'

gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-namespace'
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-rack-cache'
gem 'faraday-http-cache'

gem 'haml'

gem 'uuid'

gem 'curb'
gem 'pismo'
gem 'draper'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'select2-rails'

gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack-rewrite'

gem 'font-awesome-rails'

gem 'workflow'
gem 'ruby-graphviz'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby # helps execjs run
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'client_side_validations', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem 'exception_notification', '4.0.1'

gem 'pg'
gem 'valid_email', require: 'valid_email/validate_email'
gem 'devise_zxcvbn', github: 'bitzesty/devise_zxcvbn'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
end

gem 'cryptopay'
gem 'bitbank'
gem 'bitcoin-ruby', require: 'bitcoin'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.8'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6.3'
gem 'griddler'
gem 'griddler-mandrill'

group :development, :test do
gem 'logstasher'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
gem "mailcatcher"
gem "faker"
gem "capybara"
gem "database_cleaner"
gem "launchy"
gem "poltergeist"
end

group :heroku, :production do
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'puma'
end

gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'es5-shim-rails'
gem 'prefixfree-rails'
```

I can run the rails server from terminal, but not using rubymine. 
I've also manually installed gem js_regex but still got that error

Comment: Have you tried manually selecting the Ruby SDK in the RubyMine settings?

Comment: what shows the `bundle show js_regex` command from shell?

Comment: @jbehrens, yes - I have `ruby-2.2.1 -p85` selected  
@МалъСкрылевъ `bundle show js_regex` shows:
`/home/elena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@sestertius/gems/js_regex-1.0.12`

Comment: Could you open the RubyMine terminal and run `which ruby ` to check if RubyMine has the correct one?

Comment: I solved the problem and answered the question bellow, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by uninstalling activerecord and installing it again, then deleted the Gemfile.lock and ran `bundle install --path vendor/cache` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801899/bundlergemnotfound-could-not-find-rake-10-3-2-in-any-of-the-sources/26231894#26231894).

My colleague and I think that something went wrong when I installed Bundler and that `--path vendoe/cache` param fixed it but we're not sure and the stackoverflow answer didn't have an explanation either..