# Could not find rake-12.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

After I restarted nginx I am getting this error out of nowhere.

> Could not find rake-12.1.0 in any of the sources
>   (Bundler::GemNotFound)

I tried bundle install, reinstalling rake changing the file where gems are installed to and deleting the gemlock file but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Here there's a similar problem, check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801899/bundlergemnotfound-could-not-find-rake-10-3-2-in-any-of-the-sources)

Comment: Can't see the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I had to specify the rvm by using the command `rvm use "name of rvm"` then run bundle install this installed rake-12.1.0 to the right rvm gemset. Thanks for all the help