# Gitlab CI: bundle could not find in locally installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, rubygems, bundler

I have quite a simple GitLab CI-setup:

1. Once per branch, a job runs which creates the `backoffice image` for my tests. The idea is to do the repetitive stuff once by creating a custom docker-image to save resources. That contains installing libraries with `apt` and `gem` and `bundle`.
2. With that `backoffice image` I execute all the tests. That runs very quickly because all the libraries are already installed in my custom image. No downloads. Nice.

It was working perfectly when I built it.

Now, a few weeks later, I come back to it and it is broken. The tests complain about missing gems:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.3.23/lib/bundler/definition.rb:508:in `materialize': 
Could not find
 passenger-6.0.14,
 sinatra-2.2.1,
 sinatra-contrib-2.2.1,
 haml-5.2.2,
 mustermann-1.1.2,
 rack-protection-2.2.1,
 tilt-2.0.10 
in locally installed gems (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

While my custom `backoffice image` shows that everything was installed correctly:

```
+ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
[... stuff removed]
Installing passenger 6.0.15 with native extensions
Fetching rack-protection 3.0.2
Installing rack-protection 3.0.2
Fetching sinatra 3.0.2
Installing sinatra 3.0.2
Fetching sinatra-contrib 3.0.2
Installing sinatra-contrib 3.0.2
Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 16 gems now installed.
```

What broke?

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr:

Installing and running must use the same `Gemfile.lock` - or none at all.

### The Reason

The eagle-eyed among you might have found the problem right away. The versions are different:

> `passenger-6.0.15` installed vs. `passenger-6.0.14` required.

The source of the problem is the `Gemfile.lock` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35361002/1025430) in a different context.

When creating the `backoffice image` I copied the `Gemfile`, but not the `Gemfile.lock`. Without the lock-file, `bundle` will install the latest of whatever matches the rather loose instructions in the `Gemfile`.

But the execution-environment for testing had a `Gemfile.lock` in place, which requests specific versions of all installed gems.

### The Background

When the setup was new, the latest-and-greatest was installed. And from that `bundle` would create the lock-file. Thus even without the stringent instructions of the lock-file, the simple `Gemfile` would come to the same setup - for now.

Weeks later, there were newer versions of the gems and latest-and-greatest versions diverged from the versions locked-in with the included `Gemfile.lock`. That caused the CI-pipeline to fail with this rather generic error-message. Cause and effect being so far apart caused me a lot of headache, which I want to save you by writing this specific article.